# PHP - SimpleXML not returning object

Tags: simplexml, php

I'm pretty stuck here on getting SimpleXML to return an object when I parse it a string that's part of an objects array.

```
$a = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><BroadsoftDocument protocol="OCI" xmlns="C" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><sessionId xmlns="">1145869290</sessionId><command echo="" xsi:type="UserCallForwardingAlwaysGetResponse" xmlns=""><isActive>false</isActive><forwardToPhoneNumber>43</forwardToPhoneNumber><isRingSplashActive>false</isRingSplashActive></command></BroadsoftDocument>';
$resultA = simplexml_load_string($a);
var_dump($resultA);

$b = $this->_request->_response->_body; // This is the same content as $a and is a string. 
$resultB = simplexml_load_string($b);   
var_dump($resultB);
```

The output of `$resultA` is an object with warning:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): namespace warning : xmlns: URI C is not absolute in /var/www/html/Broadworks.php on line 103

The output of `$resultB` is a empty object?

Both `$a` and `$b` are the same strings.

Answer (score 0):

remove `xmlns="C"` from your xml string

Comment: Found my problem, it seems SimpleXML can't parse when a soap envelope is present...