# Nusoap: parseing XML with namespase getting error

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, nusoap

I am using NuSoap for webservice. In response i am getting xml with namespace something like :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none" s:mustUnderstand="1">ABC.CS.Ia.Cts.Ees.Au/IAuth/A</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <A xmlns="ABC.CS.Ia.Cts.Ees.Au">
      <Au xmlns:d1="ABC.CS.Ia.Cts.Ees.Au" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d1:Res>Q1</d1:Res>
        <d1:n>jFn</d1:n>
      </Au>
    </A>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

$xml_feed = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

Now i want to parse it. I have used simplexml_load_string function but getting warning and nothing returned by the function.

**Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 7: parser warning : xmlns: URI BC.CS.Ia.Cts.Ees.Au is not absolute in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 38
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:  in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 38
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 38**

Please help me if any one have know..

-itin

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you aren't accessing the XML objects correctly this function will correctly retrieve xpath child items:

```
function parseSOAPXmlTest($str) {
  //parse xml      
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
  echo "xml=" . print_r($xml, true);  

  if( $xml === false ) { throw new Exception("OBJ is malformed!"); }
  foreach($xml->xpath('//s:Header') as $header) {
     if( empty($header) ) { throw new Exception("Header is malformed or missing!"); }
     echo "header=" . print_r($header, true);  
  }      

  foreach($xml->xpath('//s:Body') as $body) {

     if( empty($body) ) { throw new Exception("Body is malformed or missing!"); }
     echo "body=" . print_r($body, true);  
     foreach($body->A->Au->xpath('//d1:Res') as $Reschild) {
        echo "Reschild=" . print_r($Reschild, true);  
     }
     foreach($body->A->Au->xpath('//d1:n') as $nchild) {
        echo "nchild=" . print_r($nchild, true);  
     }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML can't parse when a soap enveloppe is present.

See below:

[PHP - SimpleXML not returning object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092079/php-simplexml-not-returning-object)