# Soap xml response parsing error in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, soap, warnings

This my php code for parsing the xml code as given below:

```
$name = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body>
    <QueryReportResponse xmlns="nPAY">
        <QueryReportResult>&lt;QueryReportResponse xmlns="nPAY" /&gt;
        </QueryReportResult>
    </QueryReportResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($name);
var_dump($xml);
```

But i am getting this kind of error as described below:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): namespace warning : xmlns: URI nPAY is not absolute in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 56

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <QueryReportResponse xmlns="nPAY"> in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 56

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 56
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) { }
```

Am I missing something ?? How to parse this kind of soap response ?

Comment: what var_dump response `false` or `null`

Comment: SimpleXML can't parse when a soap envelope is present. Find below link. Hope this will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092079/php-simplexml-not-returning-object

Comment: change xmlns="nPAY" to  valid url. The namespace (xmlns) URI needs to have http:// before it to make it absolute.

Comment: now its working.. removing soap envelope and soap body tags and adding http:// in uri thanks @VishalBharti dobule-h

Answer (score 0):

Removing soap envelope and soap body tags and adding http:// in URI section of the xmlns does the tricks.